# html5 canvas tooltip only visible for last drawn object, not for previous ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

what exactly I want to achieve is

1. to draw objects on canvas and
2. on mouseover display relevant data in tooltip.

[`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilkinkar/pwuL6cbv/) you can view the code.

```js
var canvasBack;
var canvasLabel;
var canvasDraw;
var ctxBack;
var ctxLabel;
var ctxDraw;
var last_mousex = 0;
var last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = 0;
var mousey = 0;
var canWidth;
var canHeight;
var scaleParameter;
var radius;
var xVertex;
var yVertex;
var hotspots = [];

// initialization on loading of canvas
$('canvas').ready(function() {
  init();
});

// initialization function used for binding events, and inital logic implemented.
function init() {
  scaleParameter = 1;
  canvasBack = document.getElementById('backSpace');
  canvasLabel = document.getElementById('layerCanvas');
  canvasDraw = document.getElementById('drawSpace');
  ctxBack = canvasBack.getContext('2d');
  ctxLabel = canvasLabel.getContext('2d');
  ctxDraw = canvasDraw.getContext('2d');

  canWidth = parseInt($(canvasBack).attr('width'));
  canHeight = parseInt($(canvasBack).attr('height'));

  var canvasx = $(canvasBack).offset().left;
  var canvasy = $(canvasBack).offset().top
  var mousedown = false;

  //Mousedown
  $('canvas').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    $('#drawSpace').css('display', 'block');
    last_mousex = mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
    last_mousey = mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
    mousedown = true;
  });

  //Mouseup
  $('canvas').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    hotspots.push({
      x: xVertex,
      y: yVertex,
      radius: radius,
      tip: 'You are over ' + mousex + ',' + mousey
    });
    let cw = canvasBack.width;
    let ch = canvasBack.height;
    ctxBack.drawImage(canvasDraw, 0, 0, cw, ch);
    $('#drawSpace').css('display', 'none');
    mousedown = false;
  });

  //Mousemove
  $('canvas').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
    mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
    if (mousedown) {
      // draw(mousedown);
      drawEllipse(last_mousex, last_mousey, mousex, mousey);
    } else {
      hoverTooltip();
    }
  });
}


function drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var leftScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollLeft();
  var topScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollTop();
  let cw = canvasBack.width;
  let ch = canvasBack.height;
  ctxDraw.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  var radiusX = x2 - x1,
    radiusY = y2 - y1,
    centerX = x1 + radiusX,
    centerY = y1 + radiusY,
    step = 0.01,
    a = step,
    pi2 = Math.PI * 2 - step;

  radius = Math.sqrt(radiusX * radiusX + radiusY * radiusY) / 2;

  ctxDraw.beginPath();
  ctxDraw.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctxDraw.closePath();
  ctxDraw.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctxDraw.fill();
  ctxDraw.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctxDraw.stroke();

  xVertex = centerX;
  yVertex = centerY;
}

// tooltip show on hover over objects
function hoverTooltip() {
  var leftScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollLeft();
  var topScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollTop();
  let cw = canvasBack.width;
  let ch = canvasBack.height;

  for (var i = 0; i < hotspots.length; i++) {
    var h = hotspots[i];
    var dx = mousex - h.x;
    var dy = mousey - h.y;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy < h.radius * h.radius) {
      $('#console').text(h.tip);
      ctxLabel.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
      ctxLabel.fillText(h.tip, mousex + leftScroll, mousey + topScroll);
    } else {
      ctxLabel.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#scrollParent {
  width: 644px;
  height: 364px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#scrollParent>canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
}

#backSpace {
  z-index: 0;
}

#drawSpace {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#layerCanvas {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollParent">
  <!-- actual canvas that is visible -->
  <canvas width="640" height="360" id="backSpace"></canvas>
  <!-- canvas used for drawing new objects -->
  <canvas width="640" height="360" id="drawSpace"></canvas>
  <!-- canvas used to display tooltip -->
  <canvas width="640" height="360" id="layerCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="console"></div>

</div>
```

actual problem is in the bellow image, tooltip worked fine when the 1st object was drawn, but once the second object was drawn tooltip worked only for the second one, not for previously drawn objects.

what is causing this issue, and how to fix it ?
[image]

Comment: Might it be because you only log the last drawn element? It looks like you keep overwriting the same variables.

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing else will not remove the label when leaving the elipse.

You need to exit the loop once you found the correct elipse from the array using break.

```
function hoverTooltip() {
  var leftScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollLeft();
  var topScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollTop();
  let cw = canvasBack.width;
  let ch = canvasBack.height;

  for (var i = 0; i < hotspots.length; i++) {
    var h = hotspots[i];
    var dx = mousex - h.x;
    var dy = mousey - h.y;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy < h.radius * h.radius) {
      $('#console').text(h.tip);
      ctxLabel.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
      ctxLabel.fillText(h.tip, mousex + leftScroll, mousey + topScroll);
      break; // exit the loop
    } else {
       ctxLabel.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I figured that if you draw two objects over each other, it will behave poorly. Try this instead. It will display information of the latest drawn spot.

```
function hoverTooltip() {
  var leftScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollLeft();
  var topScroll = $("#scrollParent").scrollTop();
  let cw = canvasBack.width;
  let ch = canvasBack.height;

  var spots = hotspots.filter((h) => {
    var dx = mousex - h.x;
    var dy = mousey - h.y; 
    return (dx * dx + dy * dy < h.radius * h.radius);
  })

  if (spots.length > 0) {
    var h = spots[spots.length - 1]; // latest drawn spot
    $('#console').text(h.tip);
    ctxLabel.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctxLabel.fillText(h.tip, mousex + leftScroll, mousey + topScroll);
  } 
  else
  {
    ctxLabel.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  }
}
```

Comment: See updated anwser to display information correctly when two spots are drawns over each other.

Comment: You could reduce your code by doing the `clearRect` just once at the beginning of the function, and in your updated version try changing the fillText to print all not overlap

Answer (score 2):

I see there are already a few answers. This is mine:
In order to be able to show the label for every circle on hover you need to save all your circles in am array: the `circles` array. I'm using the  `ctx.isPointInPath()` method to know if the mouse is over the circle, and if it is I paint the label.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 640;
let ch = canvas.height = 360;

let found = false;//is a circle found?

const cText = document.querySelector("#text");
const ctxText = cText.getContext("2d");
cText.width = 640;
cText.height = 360;
ctxText.font="1em Verdana";


let drawing = false;

let circles = []


class Circle{
  constructor(x,y){
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y;
    this.r = 0;
  }
  
  updateR(m) {
    this.r = dist(this,m);
  }
  draw(){ 
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI);
   }
  paint(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    this.draw();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
  
  label(m){
    this.draw();
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(m.x, m.y)) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     
    ctxText.fillStyle = "black";
    ctxText.fillText(`you are over ${this.x},${this.y}`,m.x,m.y)
    found = true;
    }
}
}
let m = {}// mouse

cText.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>{
  drawing = true;
  m = oMousePos(canvas, e);
  let circle = new Circle(m.x,m.y)
  circles.push(circle);
})

cText.addEventListener("mouseup",(e)=>{
  drawing = false; 
  
})


cText.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>{
  m = oMousePos(canvas, e);
  found = false;
  if(drawing){
    let circle = circles[circles.length-1];//the last circle in the circles arrey
    circle.updateR(m); 
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, cw,ch);
  ctxText.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch) 
  circles.map((c) => {c.paint();}); 
  for(let i = circles.length-1; i >=0 ; i--){
    circles[i].label(m);
    if(found){break;}
  }
  
  
})


function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
#scrollParent{position:relative;}
```

```html
<div id="scrollParent">
  <!-- actual canvas that is visible -->
  <canvas width="640" height="360"></canvas>
  <canvas width="640" height="360" id="text"></canvas>

</div>
```

I've updated the code in base of the comment of @HelderSepu

A SECOND UPDATE in base of a second message from @HelderSepu. He wants to see "multiple message but avoid overlapping the messages"

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 640;
let ch = canvas.height = 360;

let text = "";

const cText = document.querySelector("#text");
const ctxText = cText.getContext("2d");
cText.width = 640;
cText.height = 360;
ctxText.font="1em Verdana";


let drawing = false;

let circles = []


class Circle{
  constructor(x,y){
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y;
    this.r = 0;
  }
  
  updateR(m) {
    this.r = dist(this,m);
  }
  draw(){ 
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI);
   }
  paint(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    this.draw();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
  
  label(m){
    this.draw();
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(m.x, m.y)) {
    this.text = `[${this.x},${this.y}]`
  }else{
    this.text = "";
  }
}
}
let m = {}// mouse

cText.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>{
  drawing = true;
  m = oMousePos(canvas, e);
  let circle = new Circle(m.x,m.y)
  circles.push(circle);
})

cText.addEventListener("mouseup",(e)=>{
  drawing = false; 
  
})


cText.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>{
  m = oMousePos(canvas, e);
  
  if(drawing){
    let circle = circles[circles.length-1];//the last circle in the circles arrey
    circle.updateR(m); 
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, cw,ch);
  ctxText.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  text="";
  circles.map((c) => {c.paint();c.label(m);}); 
  circles.map((c) => {text += c.text;});
  ctxText.fillStyle = "black";
  ctxText.fillText(text,m.x,m.y)
  
})


function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
#scrollParent{position:relati
```

```html
<div id="scrollParent">
  <!-- actual canvas that is visible -->
  <canvas width="640" height="360"></canvas>
  <canvas width="640" height="360" id="text"></canvas>

<div id="console"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: On the original code technically there is an array of circles (`var hotspots = [];`) ... and you still have issues when circles overlap

Comment: True @HelderSepu! I've update the code in base of your comment. I think there are no more issues when circles overlap.

Comment: Instead of just drawing one message try drawing multiple message but avoid overlapping the messages

Comment: @HelderSepu please check again my demo

Comment: Nice! Yes that looks good! +1 . Do you think you can put them on different lines?

Comment: @enxaneta your code is a good work, it covered most of the scenario, but the selected answer worked for what I wanted to achieve.